# Show number of occurences in custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I have two custom post types; `player` and `fixture`.
When a fixture is done I select the players who attended the match via an Advanced Custom Fields Relationship field.

On the players' single page I would like to print the number of fixtures the players have participated in (think of a basic statistics table).

How would i go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a counter, so you have two post types: Players and Fixtures.

Create an ACF [Relationship](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/) Field Type for `Players` posts type. On single post for `Players` post type select the `Fixtures` which the individual player completed.

You can customize the ACF Relationship output and use a counter to find how many `Fixtures` you selected for the player.

```
<?php 

$posts = get_field('your_relationship_field_name');

if( $posts ):
    // setup a counter for number of fixtures
    $fixtures_counter = 0;
    foreach( $posts as $post):
        $fixtures_counter ++;
        setup_postdata($post);
    endforeach;
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif; 

?>
```

the variable `$fixtures_counter` contains total number of `fixtures (posts)` selected in the relationship field which you can use to output "the number of fixtures the player have participated in".